# questdb Column names must be unique on web console

Tags: questdb

what is wrong at my define of a table ?
Thanks for your help.
Defines in the web-Console:

```
Table name Partition by WAL
testtable  hour      disabled
     columns
  Column names must be unique
datetime              timestamp
x designated
total                 float
yesterday             float
```

I tried on Webconsole http://127.0.0.1:9000/ to define a Table with some colums an got an error like in the picture. I found all colums are unique, so i dont understand the error.

with regards
bruno

Answer (score 1):

QuestDB Developer Advocate here. Sorry to see this happening!

I just tried that on 7.3.5 (latest development branch, directly compiling from source) and could create my table. See attached screenshot.

We commented this on the core QuestDB slack and one of our designers mentioned that this is indeed a bug and it has been recently fixed. It should be deployed in our next release, hopefully by the end of the week.

For the time being you can either compose your create table statement by hand (happy to help if needed, just jump into slack.questdb.io and ask away), downgrade to a earlier version, or compile manually (maybe not worth it as the fix will be released soon).

[image: create table screenshot]